syntax error at or near "GENERATED"
Please somebody inspect my code to see why I get syntax error
TABLE:
CREATE TABLE post_partitioned (
pk integer,
title TEXT,
content TEXT,
author INTEGER,
category INTEGER,
reply_to INTEGER,
created_on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
last_edited_on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
editable BOOLEAN,
likes INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT created UNIQUE ( pk, created_on )
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_on);

EXPRESSION:
ALTER TABLE post_partitioned ALTER COLUMN pk TYPE int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

This should be posted on Stackoverflow instead, but already has an answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55556529/75852

I’m voting to close this question because it has a duplicate on the site it belongs on.

The error occurs because a table with a unique constraint or a primary key cannot be partitioned directly in PostgreSQL. The unique constraint (CONSTRAINT created UNIQUE (pk, created_on)) spans across multiple partitions, which isn't allowed in the current implementation of PostgreSQL partitioning.
To fix this, you can create the table without the unique constraint and then add the unique constraint on each partition individually.
